# Compile error Method or data member not found

Tags: vba, vb6

I am getting the compile error, method or data member not found. This code is previously compilable with no issues. (Havent had to compile it for almost a year). It highlights both `.Value =`.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    cmdClose.Visible = False
    cmdRun.Visible = False
    lblRun.Visible = False
    dtBeginDate.Value = Format(Now, "short date")
    dtEndDate.Value = Format(Now, "short date")
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing the code to `.Value = Now` on both lines

Comment: No way to test, but try `Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")`?

Comment: `dtBeginDate.Value = Format(Now, "short date")` works just fine here if it's the `DTPicker` control from `MSCOMCT2.OCX`. Perhaps you can tell us what type of control `dtBeginDate` is?

Comment: sorry it took so long for me to see this, it is the DTPicker control

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I did VB6 but...

You may have turned on 'option explicit' which has changed how fussy the compiler is.

- dtBeginDate.Value is probably type 'date'
- Format(Now, "short date") is type 'string'

Try this:

```
dtBeginDate.Value = Now
dtEndDate.Value = Now
```

If you want to remove the time portion of 'Now' you may need to do something like this:

```
Dim dateNow As Date
dateNow = DateValue(Now)
dtBeginDate.Value = dateNow 
dtEndDate.Value = dateNow
```

Comment: I tried both turning off option explicit and changing to the dateNow format, and still recieve the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

how about changing the code to:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    cmdClose.Visible = False
    cmdRun.Visible = False
    lblRun.Visible = False
    dtBeginDate.Value = Date
    dtEndDate.Value = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: That kept the same issue

Comment: Hmmm, then it seems that there is something wrong with the OCX as it should work perfectly normal... Have you tried a new empty project with only the datepicker to check our examples?
Otherwise try re-registering the OCX, and it that fails, reinstall the OCX.
If it fails on Value, and it is the default microsoft datepicker from the MSCOMCT2.OCX then there is certainly something wrong with the OCX

Comment: I think you found the issue. I cannot seem to get the ocx to register though. I do it through the elevated cmd and it says it registered successfully,  but then using a the nirsoft register viewer it doesnt show up as registered, and when I go into the project it is saying it isnt registered.

Comment: Have tried first to unregister it first? then reboot and register it.. Or try something like cleansweep and let it fix the registry and then retry it..

Comment: I did unregister, then register, I havent tried cleansweep, let me try that.

Comment: I used ccleaner, and did the whole registry fix, still cant get MSCOMCT2.OCX to register.

Comment: did you try to register it in **C:\Windows\System32** or in **C:\Windows\SysWow64\** (I'm sorry to ask, don't want to treat you as a rookie).
Or is this the first time you are using VB6 with a 64bit Windows 7? It might be you need to run the IDE in elevated mode..

Comment: I tried to register it to both of them. (Dont be sorry, I am a rookie to VB) Also I did try running it in elevated mode..

Answer (score 0):

A `"Method or data member not found"` error probably means that `dtBeginDate` and `dtEndDate` don't actually have a `.Value` property.

Try setting the `.Text` property instead.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    cmdClose.Visible = False
    cmdRun.Visible = False
    lblRun.Visible = False
    dtBeginDate.Text = Format(Now, "short date")
    dtEndDate.Text = Format(Now, "short date")
End Sub
```

Comment: That has not worked either. Keep in mind this was completely working code with no change. I don't know whether it is not letting me compile because of windows updates (i have seen a few of those online), or what. Thank you for your help. If you get any more ideas let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob,

Here's the deal: You need to first identify what kind of object dtBeginDate and dtEndDate are. Until you know that, you're going to be running around in circles.

Can you find the line of code that declares these dtBeginDate and dtEndDate variables? For example, you show that dateNow is declared as a Date data type. But I don't see what dtBeginDate or dtEndDate are...

If you have controls on the form named dtBeginDate and dtEndDate, then that means there is a DLL or OCX that contains the control code. It also means that your project has a reference to the DLL/OCX that provides the object you've named "dtBeginDate".

If the code used to work then obviously you do not have a coding issue.

To best help you, let's first identify if dtBeginDate has been declared as a variable of a certain type--or if it is the name of a control that's on a form.

Comment: Ya, in the comments we figured that out. SuperDre pointed me to the ocx i need to register. Now the issue is the fact that the ocx refuses to actually register. (mscomct2.ocx) I believe if I actually get that running, then I will be set.

Comment: Where on your system is the mscomct2.ocx file that you're trying to register (i.e., what is the folder name)? What version of Windows are you using (version and bit-type)? When you're not in an elevated CMD prompt, can you still see the mscomct2.ocx file when you browse the folder that contains it? Did you try running the nirsoft tool in an elevated command prompt or as Admin--and in that context does it see that the OCX is registered?

Comment: I have tried Syswow64, and system32 for folders, I have used elevated cmd, yes I can see it. It says I registered successfully. I have windows 7 64 bit, and the tool (in elevated) does not see it registered

Comment: Do you know that the VB6 IDE is not supported under Windows 7 64-bit? I think you should make a 32-bit virtual machine that supports the IDE (such as Windows XP 32-bit), install VB6 there from its setup disc, and then manage, debug, and compile your 32-bit exes there. The compiled 32-bit EXEs will run successfully under Windows 7 64-bit (as long as you supply all of the necessary dependencies in the Setup program for your VB6 app).