# Compile error vba - I want to overwrite it

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I read the following:
[Compile error Method or data member not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442394/compile-error-method-or-data-member-not-found)
However, I am not allowed to download anything on the work computer. Hence I'm trying to overwrite the compile error by having a Userform appear with dropdown dates for people to use when they do not have on their computer the Calendar Date picker option available.

Is there any way that I can overwrite a compile error? I have tried the following code:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo EnterDateManually
        If IsDate(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            Me.MonthView1.Value = ActiveCell.Value
        End If
EnterDateManually:
    Enter_Date.Show
    End Sub
```

But it still gives me the compile error. The compile error highlights MonthView1 since on this computer I removed the missing References library since I don't have it on this computer and I'm sure other user won't have it either on their computer.

I know when you get an error with number you can overwrite it (though you should try to fix it first :-) but it seems that overwriting the Compile error is not possible? Or is it...
Thanks for you help

Comment: I think you mean "override" the error, not "overwrite"? "Override" would be "error handling" where you deal with error conditions that come up while your code is executing and deal with them gracefully instead of having the application just collapse in a pile. "Overwrite" would be what you do when you turn off "insert mode" on the keyboard and something new replaces what was old.

Comment: That said, you cannot "overwrite" _or_ "override" a _compiler_ error. I'm not sure what the actual error message is that the compiler is giving you (showing that would be most helpful), but you'll have to fix that before VBA will even attempt to run your code. It sounds like `MonthView1` is a control from a DLL or OCX that is being used on the form. It sounds like not everyone has this control set installed on their machine.

Comment: If neither user will have the reference library you need, why include that line at all? Why not simply have the sub do `Enter_Date.Show`?

Comment: To my knowledge (which isn't all inclusive), you cannot get around the compile-time error for a form control. You _might_ be able to attempt to late-bind a call to a component in that DLL - if it succeeds you build the form on the fly with that control, and if it fails you build the form on the fly without that control (substitute a different one or use a different method). But that reeks of over complication - just use the method that you know will be on every machine in your user group.

Comment: @BruceWayne said what I said in about 4 words. Well done!

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan :-) I wanted to try to override (you are right it is override, I'm French so some time words are not spelled properly LOL) the compile error is because the Date picker calendar is way cooler and the design is much better then me building a form with drop downs that has YEAR, Month and days that user can select. But I guess they will have to go with this Userform. Too bad we are not allowed to download on working computers. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne. I wanted to thank the both of you on my message above but I can only refer to one person in the comment section :-)

Comment: @ValS - no worries. You write English better than a lot of Americans do. That was intended to be educational, not critical - I hope it came out the right way.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan! I prefer knowing how to write things properly so thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 3):

`Me.MonthView1` doesn't exist at compile-time, thus `MonthView1` isn't a member of `Me` - hence, *Method or data member not found*.

---

`On Error` statements are executable: by the time they get to run, the code has long been compiled already - you can't use that statement to handle a compile error.

A compile error means your code *can't compile*: there's an illegal or malformed statement somewhere, `Option Explicit` is specified and a variable isn't declared, ...or a referenced type library is missing.

By removing a `<MISSING>` type library, you're telling VBA "this project doesn't really need this library anyway" - and all would be fine *if* there wasn't anything in the project that *did* need that library.

In most cases you can late-bind a type library, and blow up at run-time instead of compile-time when that library is missing - and then yes, you can handle that with `On Error` statements.

However you can't late-bind a MSForms control that needs to show up on a `UserForm` at *design-time*, because VBA needs to load that control at *design-time*, to render the form designer.

The only way you can have a MSForms control that shows up when its library can be loaded, and doesn't when the library isn't there (I've never tried this), is by loading that library at run-time, and conditionally generating the control at run-time. Now one problem with late-binding, is that you can't bind event handlers at compile-time, and VBA doesn't let you bind event handlers at run-time, so your dynamic control can't have event handlers. But I *think* you'd still be able to inspect its state, so if you *really* want to do it, it might be feasible.

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu Guindon, I think I'll go with the "easiest" way to make sure everyone can enter the data